# Prototype button in StoryBoard?

Tags: objective-c

My app dynamically generates buttons. When the button is clicked it creates a table linked to it. I have all the table interfaces (navigation controllers, etc.) set up in storyboard. However, my main view is the home screen where the user creates buttons. Since the button isn't already there, how do I set it up so that it creates a new instance of the tableview outlined in my main storyboard? Is there a "prototype button" in storyboard? The "@selector" action for the generated button is pointing to this IBAction:

```
-(IBAction)generateTable:(id)sender {    

}
```

Can someone help me fill in the remaining code?

Also, the home screen view controller is already set up in Storyboard, with the arrow next to it.

EDIT: this picture might help understand my problem a better. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKh3k.png

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself quite easily. All you have to do is make a segue (with an identifier) in Storyboard from your ViewController to the ViewController you want it to connect to, then in the IBAction, just add the following.

```
-(IBAction)generateTable:(id)sender
{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GoToTable" sender:sender];


}
```